# Testing angular factory with promise

Tags: angularjs, jasmine, angular-mock

I have the below service that i am trying to write some unit test using jasmine,
i am using $http.get that returns a promsie.

How should i test this.

```
myApp.service("authorService", function ($http, $q, $timeout) {

    return {
        getAuthors: function () {
            var deferred = $q.defer();
            $http.get('http://localhost:3412/')
                .success(function (data) {
                    deferred.resolve(data);
                })
                .error(function () {
                    deferred.reject("Failed to get albums");
                });
            return deferred.promise;

        }
}
});
```

Could someone provide any references how should i test the above service which contains $http and promise.

Answer (score 0):

Checkout $httpBackend, an angular service for testing services using $http. https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngMock/service/$httpBackend